# Related Rates with Logs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> A particle moves along the curve given by $y=x\ln x$ so that $y$ increases at a rate of $12$ units per second. How fast is $x$ increasing when the particle is at the point $(e^2,2e^2)$?

I wasn’t in class when we learned related rates and it’s really confusing me. I know that $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ is $12$ and that you have to somehow find an equation that uses all the numbers given but I just can’t seem to figure it out.

Comment: The topic of related rates is an application of the chain rule:  $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}.$$  Write out what you are given and what you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}_{(\text{ at }x=e^2)}=(1+\ln x)_{(\text{ at }x=e^2)}=?$$

Again $$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=12$$

Finally, $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$$